# Is there an official supplement about psionics or are they only mentioned in UA-material?

Tags: dnd-5e, psionics, books

I'm a big fan of psionics (like ones described in the *Expanded Psionics Handbook* for D&D 3.5e) including character options, monsters, lore, everything in fact, and I want to use them in my D&D campaign.

Is there an official supplement about them (like the *Expanded Psionics Handbook*) or are psionics only mentioned in UA-material?

Comment: Is "psychics" being used as a synonym for "psionics" here?

Comment: yes it is @mdrichey

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### There is no supplement that directly lists all options of psychics, psionics or innate mental abilities that tap into one's power of the mind or is strictly about them.

There are several supplements which have, albeit limited, options of psychics and psionics as content, these are *Acquisitions Incorporated*, *Ghosts of Saltmarsh*, *Guildmasters' Guide to Ravnica*, *Lost Laboratory of Kwalish*, *Monster Manual*, *Mordenkainen’s Tome of Foes*,  *Out of the Abyss*, *Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide* and *Volo's Guide to Monsters*.

The most psychic content in one supplement is in *[Mordenkainen’s Tome of Foes](https://www.dndbeyond.com/marketplace/source/mordenkainens-tome-of-foes)*. The most psionic content is in the *[Monster Manual](https://www.dndbeyond.com/marketplace/source/monster-manual)* and *[Mordenkainen’s Tome of Foes](https://www.dndbeyond.com/marketplace/source/mordenkainens-tome-of-foes)*.

You may want to use the search function provided by D&D Beyond to identify which kind of [psychic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/search?q=(Psychic)), or [psionic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/search?q=Psionics) options pique your interest.